# pandas explode function only removes quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
index |  entry_terms
0     | ['Abate', 'Difos', 'Temephos']
1     | []
2     | ['a', 'b']
```

I'm trying to run the `.explode` function the entry_terms column. Doing this straight on with `df['entry_terms'].explode().to_frame()` doesn't make any changes whatsoever. So I do some troubleshooting.

`df.dtypes` looks like this:

```
Unnamed: 0       int64
entry_terms     object
dtype: object
```

and the class of the `entry_terms` is `<class 'str'>`. Someone recommends converting into a list prior to running the explode function, so I run the following: `df['entry_terms'].apply(literal_eval)` followed by `explode.to_frame`. Still no explosion/change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `df.head().to_dict()` to the question that way we can see _exactly_ what your data are and not guess if it's a list or a string that looks like a list, or something entirely different. (Plus you'll get a solution that definitely works for your data)

Answer (score 0):

To use the df.explode() function, you only need to pass one argument: the name of the column that has your list-like values.

```
df3 = df.explode('entry_terms').drop_duplicates()
```